# Test gives error on running the bat test file

Tags: api, shell, testing, curl, bats-core

Consider,
I have a shell script abc.sh

```
 execute_curl() {
    curl_command="curl"
    for arg in "$@"; do
        curl_command=$(printf "%s %s" "$curl_command" "$arg")
    done
    eval "$curl_command"
}
URL='https://some.github.com/api/v3/repos/gimlet-dev-repos/repository-name/contents/file.name?ref=branch-name’

execute_curl -s -H “Authorization: token ${TOKEN}” -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -L ”${URL}"
```

And test.bats for the same

```
@test "test-run-command perform" {
    export PATH="${RESOURCES_DIR}/mocks/:${PATH}"
    TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
    debug "TEMP_DIR: ${TEMP_DIR}"
    run abc -t TOKEN -d 'some.github.com' -o 'myorg' -r 'myrepo' -g "${RESOURCES_DIR}/mock-global" -b branch -a "${TEMP_DIR}"
    assert_success
 }
```

and in mocks directory, I have curl file to test the curl: 
for example:

```
 #!/bin/sh
string_matches_glob() {
    eval "
    case \$1 in
        $2) return 0 ;;
        *) return 1 ;;
    esac
    "
}
while getopts "H:L:o:w:" OPT; do
    case "${OPT}" in
    o) OUTPUT_FILE="${OPTARG}" ;;
    L) CURL_URL="${OPTARG}" ;;
    ?) ;;
    esac
done

if string_matches_glob "${CURL_URL}" ‘*/contents/file.name*’; then
    echo '
Content…
' >"${OUTPUT_FILE}"
    printf '%s' '200'
else
    exit 97
fi
```

Issue is if I don’t use execute_curl and use directly the curl command with argument, the tests pass but when I use execute_curl function test fails with
**97**.

**more explanation of curl file above:**

> string_matches_glob evaluates whether the first argument matches
> the glob pattern specified in the second argument. The script then
> uses the getopts command to parse command-line options and arguments
> passed to the script.
>
> There are three options that can be passed to the script:
>
> -o: specifies the output file for the script to write to
> -L: specifies the URL to be passed to string_matches_glob
>
> If the URL does not match any of the specified patterns, the script
> exits with an error code of 97.

My thinking is this line is not able to match the curl_url: 
if string_matches_glob "${CURL_URL}" ‘*/contents/file.name*’

Can you please help with changes in curl file so the test passes.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `eval` is not needed: `string_matches_glob(){ case $1 in $2) return 0;; *) return 1;; esac; }`. see [case construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05)

Comment: AND can you really use `“Authorization: token ${TOKEN}”` instead of more "normal" `"Authorization: token ${TOKEN}"`? Good luck.

Comment: Very good first question! .... but ... I've read it several times now and I'm still not sure what values for `$1` and `$2` you are using to demostrate the problem. It may be in your question, but I recommend you make a clear section at the end where you call the script with X and Y arguments and with proper cmd-line formatting. Include the exact text of error messages (I think you are doing that), just make it flow better. Good luck.

Comment: sure I will add more details

Comment: For the third file (`curl` ?), in the mocks directory, does `od -c curl | grep -cw 342` return non-zero? The code you show has smart-quotes around the glob, which the shell does not consider to be the same as single-quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I call `bash abc.sh`, the call *seems* to work.

However, when debugging (using `TOKEN=foo bash -x abc.sh`) reveals that the command that is executed is:

```
curl -s -H Authorization: token foo -H Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json -L 'https://some.github.com/api/v3/repos/gimlet-dev-repos/repository-name/contents/file.name?ref=branch-name'
```

So one thing that immediately stands out is that the way the `curl_command` is built and executed does not properly handle whitespace.

`curl` will see `-H Authorization:`and `-H Accept:` but ignore the actual values of the provided headers.

There is page on the awesome BashFAQ dedicated to the pitfalls of how to properly do this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Using a proper solution also removes the need for `eval`:

```
curl_command=()

for arg in "$@"; do
    curl_command+=("$arg")
done

curl "${curl_command[@]}"
```

This will create the expected `curl` command, with proper whitespacing:

```bash
curl -s -H 'Authorization: token foo' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' -L 'https://some.github.com/api/v3/repos/gimlet-dev-repos/repository-name/contents/file.name?ref=branch-name'
```

Not sure if this will resolve your issue but at least the call to `curl` will be correct.

What stands out next, is that the call in the test does *not* match a `curl` call.

As in, this call:

```bash
run abc -t TOKEN -d 'some.github.com' -o 'myorg' -r 'myrepo' -g "${RESOURCES_DIR}/mock-global" -b branch -a "${TEMP_DIR}"
```

would constitute this `curl` call:

```bash
curl --telnet-option TOKEN --data 'some.github.com' --output 'myorg' --range 'myrepo' --globoff "${RESOURCES_DIR}/mock-global" --cookie branch --append "${TEMP_DIR}"
```

which I don't think is what you want.

This makes me think that there is more going on in the real code than what is represented in the more minimal example.

The most likely answer is that the `curl_command` uses the input to construct the correct URL (`-d` = 'domain', `-o` = 'org', `-r` ='repo'?) but that is just a guess.

Finally, let's address the `eval` in `string_matches_glob`. I assume
this is to allow dynamically matching `$1` against `$2`. If that is the case, there are easier ways to do this, without `eval` or `case.

For instance, using [the `=~` Regular Expression matching operator](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF):

```bash
string_matches_glob() {
    local string="$1"
    local glob="$2"

    [[ "$string" =~ $glob ]]
}
```

or, if that is not available or desirable, using `grep`:

```bash
string_matches_glob() {
    local string="$1"
    local glob="$2"

    echo "$string" | grep -q -E "$glob"
}
```

As both solutions are sufficiently small, they can be used inline, without the need for a separate function:

```bash
if [[ "${CURL_URL}" =~ */contents/file.name* ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

or:

```bash
if echo "${CURL_URL}" | grep -q -E '*/contents/file.name*'; then
    ...
fi
```

You may be wondering "Why does this matter?" but the less magic you have in your code, the easier it is to debug.

All of these things make me think we don't have enough of the real code to properly debug the issue, although the most likely culprit is the `curl_command` construction.